# nf_conntrack_helper_register return error

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, netfilter

In kernel if I want to restart my conntrack registers with:

```
nf_conntrack_helper_unregister(&sip[i][j]);
....// redefinition of the sip[i][j] parameters
nf_conntrack_helper_register(&sip[i][j]);
```

the `nf_conntrack_helper_register(&sip[i][j])` will fail

what I m missing?

Here after the detailed source code:

```
static void __nf_conntrack_sip_fini(void)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ports_c; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE(sip[i]); j++) {
            if (sip[i][j].me == NULL)
                continue;
            nf_conntrack_helper_unregister(&sip[i][j]);
        }
    }
    memset(sip, 0, sizeof(sip));
}

static int __nf_conntrack_sip_init(void)
{
    int i, j, ret;

    if (ports_c == 0)
        ports[ports_c++] = SIP_PORT;

    for (i = 0; i < ports_c; i++) {
        memset(&sip[i], 0, sizeof(sip[i]));

        sip[i][0].tuple.src.l3num = AF_INET;
        sip[i][0].tuple.dst.protonum = IPPROTO_UDP;
        sip[i][0].help = sip_help_udp;
        sip[i][1].tuple.src.l3num = AF_INET;
        sip[i][1].tuple.dst.protonum = IPPROTO_TCP;
        sip[i][1].help = sip_help_tcp;

        sip[i][2].tuple.src.l3num = AF_INET6;
        sip[i][2].tuple.dst.protonum = IPPROTO_UDP;
        sip[i][2].help = sip_help_udp;
        sip[i][3].tuple.src.l3num = AF_INET6;
        sip[i][3].tuple.dst.protonum = IPPROTO_TCP;
        sip[i][3].help = sip_help_tcp;

        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE(sip[i]); j++) {
            sip[i][j].data_len = sizeof(struct nf_ct_sip_master);
            sip[i][j].tuple.src.u.udp.port = htons(ports[i]);
            sip[i][j].expect_policy = sip_exp_policy;
            sip[i][j].expect_class_max = SIP_EXPECT_MAX;
            sip[i][j].me = THIS_MODULE;

            if (ports[i] == SIP_PORT)
                sprintf(sip[i][j].name, "sip");
            else
                sprintf(sip[i][j].name, "sip-%u", i);

            pr_debug("port #%u: %u\n", i, ports[i]);

            ret = nf_conntrack_helper_register(&sip[i][j]);
            if (ret) {
                printk(KERN_ERR "nf_ct_sip: failed to register"
                       " helper for pf: %u port: %u i=%d\n",
                       sip[i][j].tuple.src.l3num, ports[i], i);
                __nf_conntrack_sip_fini();
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static void nf_conntrack_sip_restart(void)
{
    printk("*****Restart SIP Conntrack *****\n");
    __nf_conntrack_sip_fini();
    __nf_conntrack_sip_init();
}
```

when I trigger `nf_conntrack_sip_restart()` from user space the `__nf_conntrack_sip_init()` will return error

By the way the fail does not occur always. Sometimes the register success.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem with single connection, without iterating over indicies?

Comment: @Tsyvarev this is the original code of linux-3.18. I do not want to modify it

Comment: What error code does nf_conntrack_helper_register() return? Looking at the kernel source, the only probably error to receive is EEXISTS, meaning that the unregister did not work out. Did you change the port layout, causing the fini to try to release with the new map instead of the old?

Comment: @Stian Skelstad: ohhh, that was my error, You are right I changed the port layoud. I really missed that. Thank you fo your help. Please make your comment as answer and I will accept it

Comment: What error code does nf_conntrack_helper_register() return? Looking at the kernel source, the only probably error to receive is EEXISTS, meaning that the unregister did not work out. Did you change the port layout, causing the fini to try to release with the new map instead of the old?