# nf_conntrack_helper_register of unregistred port reutrn error

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I have the following code to unregister and register sip conntrack from kernel 3.18

```
static void __nf_conntrack_sip_fini(void)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ports_c; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE(sip[i]); j++) {
            if (sip[i][j].me == NULL)
                continue;
            nf_conntrack_helper_unregister(&sip[i][j]);
        }
    }
    memset(sip, 0, sizeof(sip));
}

static int __nf_conntrack_sip_init(void)
{
    int i, j, ret;

    if (ports_c == 0)
        ports[ports_c++] = SIP_PORT;

    for (i = 0; i < ports_c; i++) {
        memset(&sip[i], 0, sizeof(sip[i]));

        sip[i][0].tuple.src.l3num = AF_INET;
        sip[i][0].tuple.dst.protonum = IPPROTO_UDP;
        sip[i][0].help = sip_help_udp;
        sip[i][1].tuple.src.l3num = AF_INET;
        sip[i][1].tuple.dst.protonum = IPPROTO_TCP;
        sip[i][1].help = sip_help_tcp;

        sip[i][2].tuple.src.l3num = AF_INET6;
        sip[i][2].tuple.dst.protonum = IPPROTO_UDP;
        sip[i][2].help = sip_help_udp;
        sip[i][3].tuple.src.l3num = AF_INET6;
        sip[i][3].tuple.dst.protonum = IPPROTO_TCP;
        sip[i][3].help = sip_help_tcp;

        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE(sip[i]); j++) {
            sip[i][j].data_len = sizeof(struct nf_ct_sip_master);
            sip[i][j].tuple.src.u.udp.port = htons(ports[i]);
            sip[i][j].expect_policy = sip_exp_policy;
            sip[i][j].expect_class_max = SIP_EXPECT_MAX;
            sip[i][j].me = THIS_MODULE;

            if (ports[i] == SIP_PORT)
                sprintf(sip[i][j].name, "sip");
            else
                sprintf(sip[i][j].name, "sip-%u", i);

            pr_debug("port #%u: %u\n", i, ports[i]);

            ret = nf_conntrack_helper_register(&sip[i][j]);
            if (ret) {
                printk(KERN_ERR "nf_ct_sip: failed to register"
                       " helper for pf: %u port: %u i=%d\n",
                       sip[i][j].tuple.src.l3num, ports[i], i);
                __nf_conntrack_sip_fini();
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I developed the following code to restart the registred sip conntrack with the same first port

```
static void nf_conntrack_sip_restart(void)
{
    //here ports[] = {5060, 0}
    __nf_conntrack_sip_fini();
    memcpy(ports,newports,sizeof(ports));
    //here ports[] = {5060, 5555}
    __nf_conntrack_sip_init(); // <---- It fails
}
```

when I trigger this restart function from the user space the register of the new ports array fails

If I use other ports, then it works:

```
static void nf_conntrack_sip_restart(void)
{
    //here ports[] = {5060, 0}
    __nf_conntrack_sip_fini();
    memcpy(ports,newports,sizeof(ports));
    //here ports[] = {5061, 5555}
    __nf_conntrack_sip_init(); // <---- It works
}
```

What I m missing?

Here after the whole source code of the nf_conntrack_sip.c file with my modifications: http://vpaste.net/PgUVD

To see my modifications you can make diff with origin source code of linux 3.18

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799413/nf-conntrack-helper-register-return-error) describes the same problem? If so, why do you create the new one?

Comment: This is not the same question. The previous question was about bug of edit the ports before the unregister. This oneis using the old ports for the unregister and using a new ports in the register but the newports[0] = ports[0]

Comment: What exactly fails? What `__nf_conntrack_sip_init()` return, what it print via `printk` or `pr_debug`?

Comment: @user1034749 it prints nf_ct_sip: failed to register .... (the printk message in the code)

Comment: And what `ret` value?

Comment: It may because the previous unregister has failed. how is `sip` and `ports` defined?

Comment: @fluter there is memset to 0 of sip array after unregister in the code (please ckeck code) `memset(sip, 0, sizeof(sip));`

Comment: It's not clear what sip and ports array are, yet it's the most problematic one. Why not just post the actual code?

Comment: @fluter, the ports[] and newports[] arrays are an unsigned short arrys with same size

Comment: Is sip a pointer or array?

Comment: The signatures of the functions look like your module_init(func_name_init) and module_exit(func_name_exit) functions. If this is the case you cannot call your exit function and then call your init function, this won't work. It will likely hang your kernel. If this is the case I'll write it up with more detail as an answer. –

Comment: @Harry my functions are not the module_init() and the module_exit(). But my module_init() and module_exit() are calling them

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a modules `init` and `exit` functions directly and expect them to work without first making sure the module is no longer used in any way.

> What I'm missing?

The `init` and `exit` functions are called in a particular way ie they're safe
to make a lot of assumptions about what locks are held etc before they're
called. Your code is bypassing all of this and assuming that if called directly
they'll work. This is not the case.

If you look at `delete_module` it's non trivial, it's preparing to unload your
module and this checks if your module is being used. Lets assume your code is
currently servicing a request, you really don't want your module and it's
associated data structures to vanish while running ie undefined behavior almost
certainly resulting in a kernel panic or something much worse...

The following is a short synopsis of what the kernel does before it calls the exit routine

1. Acquire `module_lock`, wait until it can get it.
2. Check if there are modules that depend on this one.
3. Check if there is an already running `init` or `exit` routine.
4. Make sure there is an `exit` function.
5. Stop the module ie mark is as MODULE_STATE_GOING
6. Unlock `mutex_lock`

At this point we have the following comment

```
/* Final destruction now no one is using it. */
```

Your code is not doing any of the 6 steps listed above. This is the source of delete module on a 3.16 kernel which I suspect is identical to 3.18...

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(delete_module, const char __user *, name_user,
    unsigned int, flags)
{
  struct module *mod;
  char name[MODULE_NAME_LEN];
  int ret, forced = 0;

  if (!capable(CAP_SYS_MODULE) || modules_disabled)
    return -EPERM;

  if (strncpy_from_user(name, name_user, MODULE_NAME_LEN-1) < 0)
    return -EFAULT;
  name[MODULE_NAME_LEN-1] = '\0';

  if (mutex_lock_interruptible(&module_mutex) != 0)
    return -EINTR;

  mod = find_module(name);
  if (!mod) {
    ret = -ENOENT;
    goto out;
  }

  if (!list_empty(&mod->source_list)) {
    /* Other modules depend on us: get rid of them first. */
    ret = -EWOULDBLOCK;
    goto out;
  }

  /* Doing init or already dying? */
  if (mod->state != MODULE_STATE_LIVE) {
    /* FIXME: if (force), slam module count damn the torpedoes */
    pr_debug("%s already dying\n", mod->name);
    ret = -EBUSY;
    goto out;
  }

  /* If it has an init func, it must have an exit func to unload */
  if (mod->init && !mod->exit) {
    forced = try_force_unload(flags);
    if (!forced) {
      /* This module can't be removed */
      ret = -EBUSY;
      goto out;
    }
  }

  /* Stop the machine so refcounts can't move and disable module. */
  ret = try_stop_module(mod, flags, &forced);
  if (ret != 0)
    goto out;

  mutex_unlock(&module_mutex);
  /* Final destruction now no one is using it. */
  if (mod->exit != NULL)
    mod->exit();
  blocking_notifier_call_chain(&module_notify_list,
             MODULE_STATE_GOING, mod);
  async_synchronize_full();

  /* Store the name of the last unloaded module for diagnostic purposes */
  strlcpy(last_unloaded_module, mod->name, sizeof(last_unloaded_module));

  free_module(mod);
  return 0;
out:
  mutex_unlock(&module_mutex);
  return ret;
}
```

Near the end it runs your exit function but only after it makes sure that no one
is actually using it etc. To be able to call the functions the way you want you
need to understand loading and unloading modules.

**I see you've edited the question and it's now clear where the code came from**

It would have helped if you'd mentioned that that you'd cut and paste the `init` and `exit` functions from nf_conntrack_sip. It would likely have saved a lot of people a lot of time wondering why it didn't work.

Comment: It's not about module init/fini. Please check my source code. I update the question with a link to the whole source code

Comment: You cannot call a modules exit routine and expect it to work unless you first make sure the module is not in use. Please read what `delete_module` does in order to make sure the module can be safely unloaded. It's checking things like the `module_lock` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `nf_conntrack_helper_register` function fails because of duplicated entry in connection tracking table, and its return code could be 0 or -EEXIST according to its implementation in 3.18. However I didn't see any problem with your code snip, could you check other places in your code where you might insert a duplicate `nf_conntrack_helper`?

Comment: I update the question with a link to the whole source code

Comment: @MOHAMED  Sorry, I didn't see a problem when I compile your code and run it on 4.4.8. My sequence of operation is ports={6050,0}, ports_c=1; init(); fini(); ports={6050, 5555}; ports_c=2; init();.

Comment: could you try to restart many times by keeping the first port to 6633

Comment: Hi, I tested multiple restarts but still didn't see problem with that. I don't think the module init/fini as mentioned by Harry is a problem since all what he mentioned is done by module loader instead and you are only doing data structure init/fini and register...But anyway, if you check the source code of nf_conntrack_helper_register, the only reason if fails is that there is duplicate entry found in nf_ct_helper_hash. I suggest you dump its contents with hlist_for_each_entry in your module code when you see a failure from nf_conntrack_helper_register to help debug.